# How to sort an array of UIColors by color(In ROYGBIV order for example)?

Tags: swift

I have a whole bunch of colors to be displayed in my UI in an array and I think it would look the best if they were sorted by color. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: This is a unique requirement :). Are they a static set of colors such as rainbow colors or can they be random? If they are static then you can create an array in the required order itself. But if they are random then you have to define a criteria for sorting such as sort by their color components (RGB) and then based on that a sorting function can be written.

Comment: They are random(The user will be able to add their own colors)

Comment: If its random then by which color component do you want it to be sorted? There is no other characteristic of a color that you can use to sort. You will have to sort based on RGBA value in that order like one of the answers below. Will that work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot really sort an array of colors in a way that you want unless you define which color you consider as greater or lesser than another color. For e.g. you cant say that red color is greater than blue color.

You will instead have to define which component of the color you can use as a sort descriptor. For e.g if you want your array of colors to be sorted according to their Red component or green or blue component.

So your only option is to use some random characteristic of a color object as your sort descriptor. One method is to use the `hashValue` of the color object and use it to sort. I am not sure how the system calculate the hashValue of a UIColor object. So you can sort your colors array like this.

```
var colors = [UIColor.redColor(), UIColor.orangeColor(), UIColor.yellowColor(), UIColor.greenColor(), UIColor.blueColor(), UIColor.cyanColor(), UIColor.magentaColor()]
    let sortedColors = colors.sort { (color1, color2) -> Bool in
        color1.hashValue <= color2.hashValue
    }
```

If you want to sort it by Red, then green, then blue then alpha then you can use this sorting function.

```
let sortedColors = colors.sort { (color1, color2) -> Bool in
    var red1:CGFloat=0, red2:CGFloat=0
    var green1:CGFloat=0, green2:CGFloat=0
    var blue1:CGFloat=0, blue2:CGFloat=0
    var alpha1:CGFloat=0, alpha2:CGFloat=0
    color1.getRed(&red1, green: &green1, blue: &blue1, alpha: &alpha1)
    color2.getRed(&red2, green: &green2, blue: &blue2, alpha: &alpha2)
    if red1 == red2 {
        if green1 == green2 {
            if blue1 == blue2 {
                return alpha1 < alpha2
            } else {
                return blue1 < blue2
            }
        } else {
            return green1 < green2
        }
    } else {
        return red1 < red2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

How about sorting your colors by their hue:

```
extension UIColor
{
    var hue: CGFloat
    {
        var hue: CGFloat = 0
        var saturation: CGFloat = 0
        var brightness: CGFloat = 0
        var alpha: CGFloat = 0

        self.getHue(&hue,
                    saturation: &saturation,
                    brightness: &brightness,
                    alpha: &alpha)

        return hue
    }
}

let colors = [UIColor.purpleColor(),
              UIColor.brownColor(),
              UIColor.yellowColor(),
              UIColor.magentaColor(),
              UIColor.blueColor(),
              UIColor.redColor()]

print(colors.sort({ $0.hue < $1.hue}))
```

Simon

Comment: Probably the better answer as the most intuitive way to sort them is based on their position (angle) on the color wheel. +1

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
//
// 1. make category
//
@interface UIColor(myColor)
- (CGFloat) red;
- (CGFloat) green;
- (CGFloat) blue;
- (CGFloat) alpha;
@end

@implementation UIColor (myColor)

- (CGFloat) red {
    CGFloat red;
    CGFloat blue;
    CGFloat green;
    CGFloat alpha;

    [self getRed: &red green: &green blue: &blue alpha: &alpha];
    return red;
}

- (CGFloat) green {
    CGFloat red;
    CGFloat blue;
    CGFloat green;
    CGFloat alpha;

    [self getRed: &red green: &green blue: &blue alpha: &alpha];
    return green;
}

- (CGFloat) blue {
    CGFloat red;
    CGFloat blue;
    CGFloat green;
    CGFloat alpha;

    [self getRed: &red green: &green blue: &blue alpha: &alpha];
    return blue;
}

- (CGFloat) alpha {
    CGFloat red;
    CGFloat blue;
    CGFloat green;
    CGFloat alpha;

    [self getRed: &red green: &green blue: &blue alpha: &alpha];
    return alpha;
}
@end


//
// 2. sort
//
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObjectsFromArray: @[[UIColor blackColor],
                              [UIColor darkGrayColor],
                              [UIColor lightGrayColor],
                              [UIColor whiteColor],
                              [UIColor grayColor],
                              [UIColor redColor],
                              [UIColor greenColor],
                              [UIColor blueColor],
                              [UIColor cyanColor],
                              [UIColor yellowColor],
                              [UIColor magentaColor],
                              [UIColor orangeColor],
                              [UIColor purpleColor],
                              [UIColor brownColor],
                              [UIColor clearColor]]];

NSLog(@"before sorted" );
for(UIColor* color in array) {
    NSLog(@"r:%.05f, g:%.05f, b:%.05f, a:%.05f", color.red, color.green, color.blue, color.alpha);
}

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor00 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: @"red" ascending: YES];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor01 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: @"green" ascending: YES];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor02 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: @"blue" ascending: YES];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor03 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: @"alpha" ascending: YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors           = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: sortDescriptor00, sortDescriptor01, sortDescriptor02, sortDescriptor03, nil];
NSArray *sortedArray               = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: sortDescriptors];

NSLog(@"\nafter sorted" );
for(UIColor* color in sortedArray) {
    NSLog(@"r:%.05f, g:%.05f, b:%.05f, a:%.05f", color.red, color.green, color.blue, color.alpha);
}

before sorted
r:0.00000, g:0.00000, b:0.00000, a:1.00000
r:0.33333, g:0.33333, b:0.33333, a:1.00000
r:0.66667, g:0.66667, b:0.66667, a:1.00000
r:1.00000, g:1.00000, b:1.00000, a:1.00000
r:0.50000, g:0.50000, b:0.50000, a:1.00000
r:1.00000, g:0.00000, b:0.00000, a:1.00000
r:0.00000, g:1.00000, b:0.00000, a:1.00000
r:0.00000, g:0.00000, b:1.00000, a:1.00000
r:0.00000, g:1.00000, b:1.00000, a:1.00000
r:1.00000, g:1.00000, b:0.00000, a:1.00000
r:1.00000, g:0.00000, b:1.00000, a:1.00000
r:1.00000, g:0.50000, b:0.00000, a:1.00000
r:0.50000, g:0.00000, b:0.50000, a:1.00000
r:0.60000, g:0.40000, b:0.20000, a:1.00000
r:0.00000, g:0.00000, b:0.00000, a:0.00000

after sorted
r:0.00000, g:0.00000, b:0.00000, a:0.00000
r:0.00000, g:0.00000, b:0.00000, a:1.00000
r:0.00000, g:0.00000, b:1.00000, a:1.00000
r:0.00000, g:1.00000, b:0.00000, a:1.00000
r:0.00000, g:1.00000, b:1.00000, a:1.00000
r:0.33333, g:0.33333, b:0.33333, a:1.00000
r:0.50000, g:0.00000, b:0.50000, a:1.00000
r:0.50000, g:0.50000, b:0.50000, a:1.00000
r:0.60000, g:0.40000, b:0.20000, a:1.00000
r:0.66667, g:0.66667, b:0.66667, a:1.00000
r:1.00000, g:0.00000, b:0.00000, a:1.00000
r:1.00000, g:0.00000, b:1.00000, a:1.00000
r:1.00000, g:0.50000, b:0.00000, a:1.00000
r:1.00000, g:1.00000, b:0.00000, a:1.00000
r:1.00000, g:1.00000, b:1.00000, a:1.00000
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with Swift.